# sql file not working on iphone

Tags: iphone

i made a sql file and want to execute query but i dont know why my bird.sql is not working

here is my bird.sql

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "rock";
CREATE TABLE "rock" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "student" VARCHAR, "rollno" INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "rock" VALUES(1,'ram',10);
INSERT INTO "rock" VALUES(2,'sita',20);
INSERT INTO "rock" VALUES(3,'shyam',40);
COMMIT;
```

and i cannot enter into this line

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
}
```

Comment: Just saying "is not working" is not information. What doesn't work? How are you expecting it to work? What happens instead?

Comment: i am sorry, i mean my sql query is not executing.. i am using sqlite manager firefox plugin and there its working but when i export this file as bird.sql  and then execute query it fails?? any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i used terminal to write query and export it ... dont use sqlitemanager for sql query  thats it

Thanks